# Spring Integration throws exception: is a one-way 'MessageHandler' and it isn't appropriate to configure 'outputChannel'

Tags: spring, spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

this configuration in dsl throws exception: The 'currentComponent' (com.kn.einvoicing.producer.integration.OutgoingProcessingStage6Flow$$Lambda$1349/0x00000008017bae80@599f0fab) is a one-way 'MessageHandler' and it isn't appropriate to configure 'outputChannel'. This is the end of the integration flow.

```
    @Bean
    IntegrationFlow regularFlow() {
        return IntegrationFlows.from(OUTPUT_CHANNEL)
                //.split()
                .publishSubscribeChannel(subscriber -> subscriber
                                .subscribe(s ->
                                        s.filter(Payload.class, filter1())
                                          .handle(this::check())
                                          .handle(this::createPackage))                                          
                                .subscribe(s -> s.filter(Payload.class, filter2())
                                                .handle(this::createPackage))                                                
                                
                )
                .channel(OUTPUT_CHANNEL1)
                .get();
    }
        
    private Message<?> createPackage(PackagePayload payload, MessageHeaders headers) {
        //do something and return message
    }

@Bean
public IntegrationFlow outputFlow() {
    return f -> f
            .handle(Ftp.outboundAdapter(ftpSessionFactory(), FileExistsMode.REPLACE)
                    .useTemporaryFileName(false)
                    .autoCreateDirectory(true)
                    .fileNameExpression("headers['" + FileHeaders.FILENAME + "']")
                    .remoteDirectory(remoteFolder));
}

@Bean(ReceiverConstants.OUTPUT_CHANNEL)
DirectChannel outputChannel() {
    return new DirectChannel();
}
```

methods in filters look like

```
@Bean
public GenericSelector<Payload> filter1() {        
    return source -> isTrue(source);
}
```

what is the cause of that? how can I fix that? thanks in advance!

Comment: Show your `check()` method, please. And why do you show that `outputFlow()`?